# VueJs how to send a post request with parameters?

Tags: javascript, post, vuejs2

I'm sending the request this way

```
this.$http.post('http://localhost:3000/store', {something: 'string'}, {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
      }})
```

And if you look through the browser, the parameters look like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJP7h.png)

in image i show object which look like ({"something":"string"}:)

Note that my object is the key of another object
(If you use json.stringfy (), my object will still be the key of another object)
Why did it happen and how to make a normal object?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do this is create the object first.

```js
var something = "key";
var obj = {};
obj[something] = 'string';

this.$http.post('http://localhost:3000/store', obj, {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
      }})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>

var mixin = {


        var url = 'http://localhost/vue/serv.php';
        this.$http.get(url, {params: {action: 'buscar', userid:'2'}, headers: {'X-Custom': '...'}}).then(response => {
            this.usuarios = response.body;
            console.log(response);
        }, response => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}    
    }


new Vue({
    el: '#resultado', 

    mixins: [mixin], 

    data:{
        titulo: "Vue lmideias",       
        usuarios: []        
    } 

});

</script>
```

Comment: Code only answers are not considered good answers on Stack Overflow. Please add at least a sentence or two explaining how this is to be used/how it answers the question. In addition, please wrap your code in code-formatting.